# Get request value inside validation authorize function

Tags: laravel

How to get a request header in `php artisan make:request Foo`?

```
public function authorize()
{   
  dd( $this->request->header('value') );
    return ...
}
```

I send a head request and I need it's value inside the `authorize()`. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function to retrieve the `Request` object.

```
request()->header('value');
```

Answer (score 2):

FormRequest is nothing but an extension of Request. So you can do this

```
$this->header('value')
```